# brew install mongodb => result => curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb, curl, download, homebrew, connect

I've an issue for installing mongodb with `brew install mongodb`. The error in terminal say that:

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Error: Failed to download resource "mongodb"
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Installing dependencies for mongodb: go, scons
==> Installing mongodb dependency: go

curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Error: Failed to download resource "go"
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.

curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Trying a mirror...


curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Error: Failed to download resource "go"
```

This is probably (I read this on other responses about the same problem) caused by a firewall or a no permise access. I’m on Mac OS X.

Answer (score -1):

First run 
    "brew update" command 
Then run brew install with sudo like 
Sudo brew install mongodb

Comment: **Don’t** use `sudo` with Homebrew.